# Why is nothing printed to the terminal when using tracing-appender?

Tags: rust, rust-tracing

I do not understand why this code doesn't print anything on my terminal:

```rust
use tracing::info;

fn main() {
    init();

    info!("test me");

    println!("i should have info! message before this")
}

pub fn init() {
    let (non_blocking, _guard) = tracing_appender::non_blocking(std::io::stdout());

    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        // .with_writer(non_blocking) // with this info! is not printed
        .init();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tracing_appender` doesn't write the logs to its output immediately, but buffers them for some time. Therefore, this `info` output is stored in the buffer, `println` executes, `main` returns, and program is terminated before the log gets printed.

To ensure that the logs will be flushed, you must use the returned `guard` value. According to [documentation](https://docs.rs/tracing-appender/latest/tracing_appender/non_blocking/struct.WorkerGuard.html), you're expected to store it in variable which is dropped after all the logs were sent - for example, at the end of `main`; therefore, this will *almost* work:

```
use tracing::info;

fn main() {
    let guard = init();

    info!("test me");

    println!("i should have info! message before this")
}

pub fn init() -> tracing_appender::non_blocking::WorkerGuard {
    let (non_blocking, guard) = tracing_appender::non_blocking(std::io::stdout());

    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .with_writer(non_blocking)
        .init();

    guard
}
```

I say "almost", because it will still first execute `println!`:

```
i should have info! message before this
2022-08-03T18:08:51.728620Z  INFO playground: test me
```

It's not advised to mix `tracing` logs and `print`s in general, precisely because of the buffering. In this specific case, however, it's possible to get the result you want - just add `drop(guard)` before `println`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works.

Is there a way to not have in `main()` the code that drop the `guard` coming from `init()`?

Comment: In the provided code, guard will be dropped automatically at the end of `main`, you don't have to do this explicitly. Explicit `drop` is used only to ensure ordering between `tracing` and non-`tracing` logs.

Comment: Yeah. I know. But I don't want to clippy warnings in console. Should I disable clippy warning about `unused variable` check?

Comment: I can use `let _guard = init();` and it does not complain about.

Comment: There is also a similar question in the tracing issues https://github.com/tokio-rs/tracing/issues/1493#issuecomment-894352695